# in Excel 2007 how to take a number in a cell and extract only a portion of it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

Ive got multiple rows in a column that's 10 digits long, and need to take the 7 digits of the right and post in the next column/row beside it. Is there a way a generate this in a Macro?

```
2300056711   0056711
2311080900   1080900
```

Comment: Do you mean just `=RIGHT(A1,7)`?

Comment: Also formatting the cell to "0000000" and doing `=MOD(A1,10000000)` is possible :P

Answer (score 3):

Fairly simple RIGHT() function

```
=Right(A1,7)
```

[image]

Comment: may or may not be important to note, the formula will convert the number to a text.

Comment: Which is what the OP wants, or the leading 0 would disappear. @ForwardEd but a good warning

Answer (score 0):

Below formulas also retrieve the same

1) `=MID(A1,LEN(A1)-6,LEN(A1)-(LEN(A1)-7))`

2) `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,(LEN(A1)-7)),"")`

**OP**

[image]